# Can't Debug on iPhone device although the provisioning profile is setup

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am new to iPhone development, I am using **xCode 4.4.1**

1. I have setup a Provisioning profile and was able to debug on my iPhone device before
2. I have disconnected my device from the machine and restarted it
3. Once reconnected my device doesn't appear on the available Scheme Destinations

Having that said:

- I have verified that the provisioning profile is properly set on my
  device @ **Settings->General->Profile**
- Using **xCode->Organizer->Devices**, I have verified that the Provisioning profile is properly set on the
  dev machine.

**Since restarting my physical iPhone device I can't use it for debugging, why ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

~Nadav

Comment: What does organizer say when you select the device there?

Comment: Also, do you get an error when you try to build? Or is your device simply not recognized?

Comment: right the Organizer say:The version of iOS on "...iPod" does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update the latest version of the iOS SDK;

Having that said, I need to use xcode 4.4.1 inorder to support armv6 compilation, and thus, in-order for this to work I need to downgrade  the iPod OS, how do I do that? where do I get a Legacy OS version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that while I was trying to generate armv6 code I was experimenting with xcode v4.4.1, this xcode version doesn't support iOS 6, and thus, it didn't recognize my device.